# What does the syntax function() { name = function() {} mean in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, syntax

I'm trying to understand the following code block and am a bit stumped.. specifically I'm confused as to what the YAHOO.example.XHR_JSON = part is about.  It looks like we're creating an anonymous method that creates a named anonymous method?

```
YAHOO.util.Event.addListener(window, "load", function() {
    YAHOO.example.XHR_JSON = function() { (blah blah blah) };
```

If I try changing the YAHOO.exmaple.XHR_JSON to something like FooBar and I get told that foobar is not defined.

Any help is as always greatly appreciated..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`XHR_JSON` is just a property of the `YAHOO.example` object. You can assign anything to this property, including a function.

If you tried the following:

```
YAHOO.util.Event.addListener(window, "load", function() {
    YAHOO.example.XHR_JSON = 'foobar';
});
```

.. then `YAHOO.example.XHR_JSON` will be set to `'foobar'` eventually, but only after the `load` event has fired. That is probably why you got `undefined` when you checked for the value.

Answer (score 0):

There are two anonymous functions.  The first sets `YAHOO.example.XHR_JSON` to the value of the second anonymous function.  This isn't the same as defining a named function.  It's just setting a variable to a value that is another function.  It's a way of deferring execution.  Maybe a second example would help:

```
var lightFuse = function() { bomb.actionToTakeIn30Seconds = function() { beep(); explode(); } }
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be the line generating the confusion

```
YAHOO.example.XHR_JSON = function() { (blah blah blah) };
```

This is assigning a function object to a property `XHR_JSON` on the property `example` on `YAHOO`.

It could have been separated out as follows

```
var v1 = YAHOO.example
v1.XHR_JSON = function() { ( blah blah blah) };
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you just needed to define FooBar first...?  e.g.

```
var FooBar = function() { alert("Foo"); }
var OtherFunction = function() {
    this.myFunc = FooBar;
}
var instance = new OtherFunction();
instance.myFunc();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var foo = funvtion(){... code ...};
```

is pretty much the same as

```
function foo() { ... code... };
```

The main idea of the code is that the XHR_JSON assignemnt is done after the "load" event of the page is triggered and all DOM elements are established.